# Login with existing user token in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The situation is : I logged in anonymously somewhere, and in my web app I receive the logged in user's token (or any information of this user). Is it possible to use this user token to log in firebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit what specific token you're talking about. But if it's the user's ID token, then you can't really authenticate with that.

What you **can** do is send requests using that ID token, and those requests will be executed by the system as if they are coming from the user that the token identifies. But the ID token expires in an hour, at which point requests with that token will be rejected. The original client will automatically refresh the ID token before this happens, but other devices won't able to do so.

Also see:

- [Demystifying Firebase Auth Tokens](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c)